# Determine coefficients so the formula $\int_{-1}^1 f(t)\,dt=w_0f(0)+w_1(f(-1)+f(1))+w_2(f(-c)+f(c))$ integrates exactly.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I want to determine the coefficients $w_0,w_1,w_2$ and $c$ of the integration formula $$\int_{-1}^1 f(t) \, dt = w_0f(0)+w_1(f(-1)+f(1))+w_2(f(-c)+f(c))$$
so that it integrates exactly the polynomials with the highest possible degree.

I have done similar problems to this one, for example, when finding the weighs of the Simpsons rule. However, in this case I don't know which is the highest possible order of the polynomial, I also don't know what to do with $c$.

Comment: Hint: $c$ is like the weights a variable to be determined for your particular choice of RHS. Use $f(t)=t^n$ for $n=0,1,2,...$ to obtain equations in the four unknowns and continue until you get enough equations to solve all of them uniquely. As for the maximum power, you have 4 unknowns and therefore need at least 4 non-trivial equations, and combine that with what happens for odd functions $f(t)$.

Comment: @RonaldBlaak I get the system $\begin{cases} 2=w_0+2w_1+2w_2 \\ 2/3=2w_1+w_22c^2 \\ 2/5=2w_1+w_22c^4 \\ 2/7= 2w_1 + w_22c^6 \end{cases}$ is it correct? I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Use the second and third equation to express $w_1$ and $w_2$ in terms of $c$. Inserting those results in the last will give you an equation in $c$ only, which you will be able to solve. Using the first equation will give you the value of $w_0$.

Answer (score 0):

This was a difficult problem until about $1826$ when Jacobi pointed out that for any integer $0\le k\le n$, the quadrature rule $Q_n$ has degree of exactness $n-1+k$ if and only if

(i) $Q_n$ is interpolatory
(ii) The node polynomial $\omega_n$ is orthogonal to all polynomials of degree less than $k$.

So condition (ii) gets you $c$ by orthogonality with $p(x)=x$ and then condition (i) gets you $w_0$ with $f_0(x)=(x^2-1)(x^2-c^2)$ and so on.

Hopefully the proof of the theorem will be considered obvious enough to a modern reader. Alternatively one might recognize the Gauss-Lobatto $5$-point rule in the problem statement.